# Smooth scroll using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html page and menu

Menu :

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
       <li>
          <a href="#info">info</a>
       </li>
         ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Part of content :

```
<div id="info" class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>       
     </div>
</div>
```

And I want to add smooth page scroll to an anchor. So I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

});
```

But it doesn't work. And scroll isn't smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your jQuery function with this:

```
$(function() {
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
});
});
```

Comment: And what's the difference ?

Comment: Wait you replaced `$(document).ready(function($) {` with `$(function() {` ? that's all??

Comment: Please try to explain your changes. A *"Because it works now"* is not helpful to anyone :(

Comment: I've read through it a couple of times, and I can't see any difference that would fix the issue *at all* ?

Comment: If it still doesn't work for you, check if you connected the jQuery library to your project correctly. And let me know if you succeed because I'm quite curious.

Comment: Then it should be easy to explain the changes in your answer, and why it works, it's only the DOM ready handler *(which doesn't matter at all)* and the added quotes *(which actually does matter)*.